# Concurrent Collection with fastest possible Add, Remove and Find the highest

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, concurrent-programming, concurrentdictionary

I am doing some heavy computations in C# .NET and when doing these computations in parallel.for loop I must collect some data in collection, but because of limited memory I can't collect all results, so I only store the best ones.

Those computations must be as fast as possible because they are already taking too much time. So after optimizing a lot I find out that the slowest thing was my `ConcurrentDictionary` collection. I am wondering if I should switch to something with faster add, remove and find the highest (perhaps a sorted collection) and just use locks for my main operation or I can do something good using `ConcurrentColletion` and speed up it a little.

Here is my actual code, I know it's bad because of this huge lock, but without it I seem to lose consistency and a lot of my remove attempts are failing.

```
 public class SignalsMultiValueConcurrentDictionary : ConcurrentDictionary<double, ConcurrentBag<Signal>>
{
    public  int Limit { get; set; }
    public double WorstError { get; private set; }

    public SignalsDictionaryState TryAddSignal(double key, Signal signal, out Signal removed)
    {
        SignalsDictionaryState state;
        removed = null;

        if (this.Count >= Limit && signal.AbsoluteError > WorstError)
            return SignalsDictionaryState.NoAddedNoRemoved;

        lock (this)
        {
            if (this.Count >= Limit)
            {
                ConcurrentBag<Signal> signals;
                if (TryRemove(WorstError, out signals))
                {
                    removed = signals.FirstOrDefault();
                    state = SignalsDictionaryState.AddedAndRemoved;
                }
                else
                    state = SignalsDictionaryState.AddedFailedRemoved;
            }
            else
                state = SignalsDictionaryState.AddedNoRemoved;

            this.Add(key, signal);
            WorstError = Keys.Max();
        }
        return state;
    }

    private void Add(double key, Signal value)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<Signal> values;
        if (!TryGetValue(key, out values))
        {
            values = new ConcurrentBag<Signal>();
            this[key] = values;
        }

        values.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Note also because I use absolute error of signal, sometimes (should be very rare) I store more than one value on one key.

The only operation used in my computations is `TryAddSignal` because it does what I want -> if I have more signlas than limit then it removes signal with highest error and adds new signal.

Because of the fact that I set `Limit` property at the start of the computations I don't need a resizable collection.

The main problem here is even without that huge lock, `Keys.Max` is a little too slow. So maybe I need other collection?

Comment: Well, make it fast and safe by giving every thread its own collection, merge the results after they are done.  Btw, this is a site where lots of professional devs visit and can help you, consider a more appropriate user name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Keys.Max()` is the killer. That's O(N). No need for a dictionary if you do this.

You can't incrementally compute the max value because you are adding *and* removing. So you better use a data structure that is made for this. Trees usually are. The BCL has `SortedList` and `SortedSet` and `SortedDictionary` I believe. One of them was based on a fast tree. It has min and max operations.

Or, use a .NET collection library with a priority queue.

Bug: Add is racy. You might overwrite a non-empty collection.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was affraid of. So I guess I cant use collections made for concurrent programming? What do you mean by a .NET collection library with a priority queue? What collection will be the fastest for my problem from these (note that sometimes signals have equal error and I need to store them)?

Comment: You are not making use of the concurrency features of those collections anyway. You have wrapped them in a lock. This is slower than using a normal dictionary. Use a priority queue. It does not matter from what library it comes. Find any such queue. You can store multiple items with equal keys by making the key `Tuple(realKey, Guid.NewGuid())` as a hack.

Comment: There are priority queues that are lock-free. Maybe you can find one on the web somewhere.

Comment: @Fucker24 Sometimes you can calculate max incrementally. If removing doesn't occur too often, it will improve the performance.

Answer (score 3):

The large `lock` statement is at least dubious. An easier improvement, if you say that `Keys.Max()` is slow, is to calculate the maximum value incrementally. You'll need to refresh it only after removing a key:

```
//...
if (TryRemove(WorstError, out signals))
{
    WorstError = Keys.Max();

//...

WorstError = Math.Max(WorstError, key);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did in the end was to implement Heap based on binary-tree as was suggested by @usr. My final collection was not concurrent but synchronized (I used locks). I checked performance thought and it does the job fast enough.
Here is pseudocode:

```
public class SynchronizedCollectionWithMaxOnTop
{
    double Max => _items[0].AbsoluteError;

    public ItemChangeState TryAdd(Item item, out Item removed)
    {
        ItemChangeState state;
        removed = null;

        if (_items.Count >= Limit && signal.AbsoluteError > Max)
            return ItemChangeState.NoAddedNoRemoved;

        lock (this)
        {
            if (_items.Count >= Limit)
            {
                removed = Remove();
                state = ItemChangeState.AddedAndRemoved;
            }
            else
                state = ItemChangeState.AddedNoRemoved;

            Insert(item);
        }
        return state;
    }

    private void Insert(Item item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
        HeapifyUp(_items.Count - 1);
    }

    private void Remove()
    {
        var result = new Item(_items[0]);

        var lastIndex = _items.Count - 1;

        _items[0] = _items[lastIndex];
        _items.RemoveAt(lastIndex);

        HeapifyDown(0);

        return result;
    }
}
```